# Replace query string in URL using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have this in URL

```
/search/?query=anything
```

and I need this

```
/search/anything/
```

where "anything" is any thing in URL after. So all I want is to cut out this part

```
?query=
```

from the middle of the URL. How?

Comment: Do you need `/search/?query=anything` to call `/search/anything/` behind the scenes or does that already work and you need `/search/anything/` to redirect to `/search/?query=anything`?

Comment: I need `/search/?query=anything` to call `/search/anything/`, so that `?query=` will be only missed in the middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a decision that my hosting provided:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^query=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?search/?$ /search/%1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/?search/(.+)/?$ /search/?query=$1
```

Answer (score 1):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^query=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^/?search/?$ /search/%1 [R=301,QSD,L]

RewriteRule ^/?search/(.+)/?$ /search/?query=$1 [L]
```

Comment: This one `RewriteRule ^/?search/?$ /search/%1 [R=301,QSD,L]` results 500 Internal Server Error, and this one `RewriteRule ^/?search/(.+)/?$ /search/?query=$1 [L]` does not give any effect.

Comment: Please consult your http server's error log file to learn what the actual cause of the http status 500 is. I do not immediately see an issue with the rules ... The second rule internally rewrites incoming requests. If that does not have "any effect" then you probbly need to check how your application logic handles such requests. I only implemented what you asked, I cannot say whether that actually makes sense ...